# Make div take up the dynamic width of sibling above while preserving flow

Tags: html, css

I'm laying out a product page in HTML. My attempt to make the desc below the photo take up the width of the photo was to use absolute positioning. This worked well until I got a longer desc and I remembered it takes the element out of the flow causing the problem below.  How should this be done?

I could not find a question that included the vertical and dynamic aspects of my question. If you are closing this as a dup please provide a link.

More details: At the top it has a div "item details" with two columns.  Left column has a photo of variable height/width. Below that I have a text description of variable size that I want exactly as wide as the photo. Right column is "item details" with a max-width div.  Below all of that I have more divs which should take the entire width.

[image]

Live url: http://www.morphmarket.com/snakes/ball-pythons/14074

HTML

```
<div class="detail-container">
    <div class="item-details">
        <div class="image-col">
            <div class="image">
                ...
            </div>

            <div class="desc">
                <b>Description.</b> {{ snake.desc }}
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="details-col">
           ...
        </div>
    </div> <!-- item details -->
    <div class="store-details">
       ...
    </div>
</div> <!-- item container -->
<div class="more-from-store">
   ...
</div>
```

CSS

```
.snake-page {
    .detail-container {
        margin-top: 10px;
        //display: table-cell;
        width: 100%;
        .item-details {
            display: table-row;
            //display: table;
            //width: 1px;
            .image, div.desc, .details-col { 
                .white-box(); 
                margin: 10px 0px;
            }
            .image-col {
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
                .image {
                    position: relative;
                    .sold {
                        size: 10rem;
                    }
                    .img-thumbnail {
                    }
                }
                div.desc {
                    max-height: 150px;
                    padding: 10px;
                    position: absolute;
                    overflow:auto;
                    left: 0px;
                    right: 0px;
                    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
                }
            }
            .details-col {
                .title {
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-size: 1.4em;
                    text-align: center;
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                }
                font-size: 1.20em;
                max-width: 400px;
                padding: 10px;
                margin-left: 10px;
                display: inline-block;
                //display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: top;
                background: @white;
                .details {
                    .dl-horizontal {
                        @width: 120px;
                        dt {
                            width: @width;
                        }
                        dd {
                            margin-left: @width + 20px;
                        }
                    }
                    .label.trait {
                        margin-right: 0px;
                    }
                }
                .button-col {
                    div {
                        margin: 0 auto;
                        width: 85%;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .store-details {
            display: table-cell;
            width: 1px;
            > * {
                .white-box();
                margin: 0 0 10px 0;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .store-policy {
            }
            .about-store {
            }
        }
    } // detail container
}
```

Comment: You can put a max-height on the description item and add overflow:auto; to it as well. This will keep the box from growing to big and should allow you to scroll in the box.

Comment: On your link the `details-col` block is below the description for me. Please copy relevant code in your question.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to set a fixed height, as I don't know how much space I actually have, and scrollbars are undesirable to me.

Comment: @caCtus, yes details-col is after the description. I don't see the question there. I will copy code.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero

Comment: Will getting the height of the combined picture and description and then applying that to the height of the other column work for you? If so, I can whip something up.

Comment: I'd prefer not to have to get dimensions, as this has not worked for me in past.  I did have something I thought was working last night, but bootstrap appears to change the behavior so it does not work the same. http://jsfiddle.net/4d5WR/121/

Comment: What should be aligned in the fiddle you just posted?

Comment: That fiddle is what I actually want, but when you add bootstrap.css it breaks it -- like this http://jsfiddle.net/4d5WR/122/

Comment: @JohnLehmann On your screenshot `details-col` is at the right, not below. I asked for code in case you were working/making tests on your link (to have "definitive" code).

Comment: Beau yes I actually happened to be looking at that last night, but haven't read it fully. I am using some display:table*s.

Comment: @caCtus I am not changing the code at that URL.  You are right though, if you have a narrow/mobile screen, then it collapses.  So my example is showing the full width.

Comment: @JohnLehmann I am not sure 1920x1080 res is what you call a narrow screen. (If it is, no problem, just wanted to "warn" you about this.) (Edit: I'm on Firefox. It's OK on Chrome. But I guess it's another issue you'll have to fix. I'm having a look!)

Comment: Thanks, can you provide link to screenshot please, and browser version?

Comment: Sure. :) http://postimg.org/image/n9bqsr51b/ Firefox 40.0.2 (I'm on Mac here.)

Comment: Thank you, I have now reproduced that with our Win/Firefox machine. That's definitely not what I want it to look like. My screenshot is Chrome and  is ALMOST what I want.

Comment: @JohnLehmann I took your Fiddle were you say the bootstrap.css file breaks your layout and wrapped your entire code with-in the bootstrap full width layout and it seems to look correct and work properly. [You can check the js.fiddle out here](http://jsfiddle.net/4d5WR/128/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find documentation that says this, but we can see that a `table-caption` element takes the width of its containing table (as opposed to stretching out based on its own amount of text like a `block` element does).

Paste this at the bottom of your CSS file to see it in action (I overrode the properties that are in the way. If you adopt this solution you can merge the styles of course).

```
.snake-page .detail-container .item-details .image-col {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.snake-page .detail-container .item-details .image-col .image {
  display: table-row;
}
.snake-page .detail-container .item-details .image-col div.desc {
  position: static;
  display: table-caption;
  caption-side: bottom;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

My solution makes both elements table related elements, the description into a `table-caption` and the image into a `table-row`, so they basically act as one table. By giving the description `caption-side: bottom` I moved the description to the bottom of the table.

Comment: This does what I need and will tide me over until I redo this whole page. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you can do this by setting rows and cols with Bootstrap and vary the sizes for the cols based on what you need. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4d5WR/124/

For example, for the image,

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="http://www.pet-care-portal.com/images/BallPythonT3Pic1.jpg">
                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I do use bootstrap grid all over my site. But here, I do not know the image width (don't know "what I need"). So I am trying to avoid a fixed width.

Comment: Does `.img-responsive` address this issue?

Comment: I'm not using that class specifically, but I am apply max-width and height directly to get the same effect. So no that doesn't address this problem.